# Add grid to an image in R

Tags: r

I would like to add a grid to an image. I used the function grid() on my image:

```
plot(image_map, axes=FALSE)
grid(5, 5, lwd = 2, col = "red")
```

I obtained a grid associated to the plot area of Rstudio, not associated to the image, i.e. the grid doest not start in the corner of the image.

I would like the grid applied only to the image, not the plot and also that the grid starts on one corner of the image. Is there another function to do it ?

Comment: Could you please post a picture of the result you expect to get ?

Comment: Try to add ```par(xpd=TRUE)``` before plotting the graph.